# OAuth in gRPC using Java

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, grpc-java

I'm trying to implement OAuth2 between my gRPC server and client applications using interceptors, with the following steps:

1. client app calls a server's gRPC method
2. server app responds with `UNAUTHENTICATED` status and a `redirect-url` in the headers
3. client obtains the `redirect-url`, uses it to access Authorization server, and finally gets an `access_token`
4. client app calls a server's gRPC method (this time, with `access_token`)

However, step #4 seems impossible in just one call since the transaction is already closed at step #2. Is there a way to do these 4 steps in just one gRPC service call?

Here is my ClientInterceptor class. I indicated the 4 steps in the code (see code comments).

```
public class OAuthClientInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor {

    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> interceptCall(MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT> method, CallOptions callOptions, Channel next) {

        return new CheckedForwardingClientCall<ReqT, RespT>(next.newCall(method, callOptions)) {

            @Override
            public void checkedStart(Listener<RespT> responseListener, Metadata headers) {

                if (redirectUrl != null) {
                    try {
                        //[Step #3] Obtain the access token
                        accessToken = obtainAccessToken(redirectUrl);
                    } catch (ConnectException e) {
                        throw new StatusRuntimeException(Status.UNAUTHENTICATED.withCause(e));
                    }
                }
                if (accessToken != null) {
                    headers.put(Key.of("Authorization",
                        Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER), "Bearer " + accessToken);

                }
                if (recursiveCall) {
                    //[Step #4] PROBLEM: still results to UNAUTHENTICATED
                    next.newCall(method, callOptions).start(responseListener, headers);
                    recursiveCall = false;
                    return;
                }
                OAuthResponseListener<RespT> oAuthRespListener = new OAuthResponseListener(responseListener);
                oAuthRespListener.setUnauthenticatedListener(trailers->{

                    //[Step #2] Obtain the redirect-url
                    redirectUrl = trailers.get(Key.of("redirect-url", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER));
                    recursiveCall = true;

                    //[Step #3 and 4] Invoke the retrieval of access token and the 2nd call to gRPC method
                    checkedStart(responseListener, headers);
                });
                //[Step #1] Call the gRPC method
                delegate().start(oAuthRespListener, headers);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I have asked this question on the grpc-java GitHub account here is the link https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/6638

Comment: Here is the answer for this question on github. https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/5856#issuecomment-511077021

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue, but I was hoping to find some built-in authentication mechanism or multiple calls to a blockingStub function to support this oAuth flow, but couldn't find any.

So I resorted to calling `blockingStub.invokeServerMethod()` at least twice;

1. to know if it's not yet authenticated, and to be able to obtain `redirect-url`
2. to be able to call `invokeServerMethod` with `access_token` attached to headers.

Note that I have 30 server methods, and I have to implement the same steps to all of these method calls. To minimize code duplicates for each server method, I created a `RetryUtil` class which will be called for each server method. Here's what I did:

```
public class GrpcClient {

    public SomeResponse callServerMethod() {
        //invoke the method twice
        return RetryUtil.retry(() -> blockingStub.invokeServerMethod(), 2); 
    }
}

public class RetryUtil {

    public static <T> T retry(Supplier<T> supplier, int retryCount) {

        StatusRuntimeException finalEx = null;
        for (int i=0; i<retryCount; i++) {
            try {
                return supplier.get();
            } catch (StatusRuntimeException e) {
                if (e.getStatus() != Status.UNAUTHENTICATED) {
                    throw e;
                }
                finalEx = e;
            }
        }
        throw finalEx;
    }
}
```